# How do I get an HP 1018 laser printer to work on 12.04?

Tags: hardware, printing

**edit** : already printed on windows-machine

Ubuntu 12.04, LJ 1018.

I've tried making foo2zjs from sourse.

I've downloaded firmware and placed it where necessarily manually from [here](http://foo2zjs.rkkda.com/firmware/sihp1018.tar.gz)

I've also tried [this](http://ptspts.blogspot.com/2010/06/how-to-fix-hp-laserjet-1018-on-ubuntu.html) - same as manual dowload but with some patches like stoping cups, etc..

I've fixed `usbfs: process 11200 (usb) did not claim interface 0 before use`
 problems using `sudo rmmod usblp` as described [here](http://habrahabr.ru/post/134973/).

And now I have

```
Aug 10 11:51:59 pav /usr/sbin/hplj1018: foo2zjs: usb://HP/LaserJet%201018?serial=KP07RLV... download failed.
Aug 10 11:51:59 pav /usr/sbin/hplj1018: foo2zjs: loading HP LaserJet 1018 firmware /lib/firmware/hp/sihp1018.dl to CUPS USB device ...
```

error.

Before that prinet was stucking on "Sending data to printer". Now it's code is "Not connected".

Unless

```
ben@pav:~$ lsusb 
...
Bus 001 Device 015: ID 03f0:4117 Hewlett-Packard LaserJet 1018
```

Thank you.

Comment: Hp printers work out of box, try reconnecting it.

Comment: @BigGenius, 10хх series need to be pre-reflashed with official firmware, as far as I understood. And it doesn't work in Ubuntu. Or I've made something wrong. Anyway, everything is printed already.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solved my problem by using the Terminal to install the driver. Open the Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and run this command:

```
sudo hp-setup
```

Trying without `sudo` could not install the driver.

Comment: this seems like the answer. in 12.04, the driver is already installed (`hplip`) and connecting the printer asks for proprietary plugins and opens a terminal procedure that does not seem to work. other methods that i tried didn't work, but doing what is said here opens a  HP GUI installer that does all the job, including adding the printer

Comment: I noticed that the printer needs to be turned on while booting ubuntu, otherwise it does not work (you can manually copy the firmware after boot, but I do not remember the exact locations from/where to copy).

Comment: if you get an error "error: hp-setup requires GUI support (try running with --qt3)" try installing hplip-gui

Answer (score 1):

Steps for solving hp 1018 problems

```
sudo apt-get remove hplip*
sudo apt-get install hannah-foo2zjs printer-driver-foo2zjs-common printer-driver-foo2zjs
sudo getweb 1018
```

reconect printer, no need for restart